# Prove that the $n$th positive nonsquare integer is $n+\{ \sqrt{n} \}$ where $\{x\}$ is denotes the integer closest to $x$.

Tags: induction

For any positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ denote the $n$th positive nonsquare integer, i.e.,

- $f(1)=2$
- $f(2)=3$
- $f(3)=5$
- $f(4)=6$
- etc.

Prove that $f(n)=n+\{ \sqrt{n} \}$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the integer closest to $x$ (for example, $\{\sqrt{1}\}=1$, $\{\sqrt{2}\}=1$, $\{\sqrt{3} \}=2$, $\{\sqrt 4 \}=2$,...)

Comment: What are your attempts?

Answer (score 3):

This was fun! Thanks for asking it ^_^

The key observation is this:

$$f(n^2) = n^2 + n$$

After all, there are $n$ squares $\leq n^2$ that we had to skip along the way.

I'll write this somewhat more suggestively as

$$f(n^2) = n^2 + \left \{ \sqrt{n^2} \right \}.$$

Now let's see what happens as we increment $n^2$. We want to understand what happens everywhere between $f(n^2)$ and $f((n+1)^2) = f(n^2 + 2n + 1)$. So we want to look at $f(n^2 + k)$ for $1 \leq k < 2n + 1$.

The next square happens at $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1$, which is $n+1$ steps away from $f(n^2)$. So we'll split this region into two pieces:

- First we'll look at $1 \leq k < n+1$
- Then we'll look at $n+1 \leq k < 2n+1$

---

For $k < n+1$, we have no fears! We don't see any more square numbers, and this makes counting the nonsquares particularly easy:

$$f(n^2 + k) = f(n^2) + k = n^2 + k + n$$

So we're led to a natural question: For $k < n+1$

$$n \overset{?}{=} \left \{ \sqrt{n^2+k} \right \}$$

And the answer is easily seen to be *yes*. Intuitively, this is because $n^2+n$ is closer to $n^2$ than it is to $(n+1)^2$. I'll leave it to you to formalize the argument. (As a hint: $\sqrt{n^2 + n} = n \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}}$, and you might imagine $\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}}$ doesn't change the value when we round to the nearest integer).

---

For $n+1 \leq k < 2n+1$, we've seen exactly one new square. So

$$f(n^2 + k) = f(n^2) + k + 1 = n^2 + k + n + 1$$

Again, you see the question coming: For $n+1 \leq k < 2n+1$

$$n + 1 \overset{?}{=} \left \{ \sqrt{n^2 + k} \right \}$$

And again, it's easy to see the answer is *yes*. This is (intuitively) because $n^2 + n + 1$ is now closer to $(n+1)^2$ than to $n^2$. You can do a similar manipulation to my previous hint to formalize this intuition.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Do you have a complete approach？？